# Magento specific attribute per category

Tags: php, magento

I want to only display specific attribute to specific type of product. For example I have Shoes and a footID. footID will only be available in Shoes product page and not any other. In time I'll also have a few more similar attributes for example tennisID that only applies to tennis Products.

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve this you first have to create all the different attributes you need. (Such as footID and tennisID)

After that you have to create multiple attribute sets. In your example you would have to create two attribute sets called "Shoes" and "Tennis".

In each of these attribute sets you add the attributes that belong to them. (Example when creating the attribute set tennis you have to add (drag) the tennisID attribute to it. (same goes for the shoes attribute set)

These attributes will only be visible (both frontend and backend) for the attribute sets they have been added too.

Regards,
Kenny